# How do I connect two objects with a method to return a new object

Tags: java, class, javascript-objects

I have 2 class objects A and B. Both contain an attribute called 'prob' (for probabillity).
Now I want to write a Method, which connects both objects and creates a new one, with a defined attribute 'prob' with "

```
A.prob(i)*B.prob(j)=C.prob(i+j).
```

Here is my code:

```
PMF add(PMF pmf){
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<x; j++){
        C.prob[i+j]=prob[i]*pmf.prob(j);
        }
    }
}
```

This is in my PMF class. I have defined in my other class (the one with the main method, it is called "Hund" )  some objects:

```
public class Hund {

public static void main(String[] args){
    PMF A= new PMF(6);
    PMF B= new PMF(6);
    PMF C= new PMF(6);
    A.setProb(1, 1);
    A.setProb(2, 1);
    A.setProb(3, 1);
    A.setProb(4, 1);
    A.setProb(5, 1);
    A.setProb(6, 1);
    System.out.println(A.prob(6));

   }
 }
```

But now, it shows me an error "C cannot be resolved to a variable". How do I make it return a PMF-Type variable? Variations I tried are e.g.:

```
PMF add(PMF pmf){
    PMF C= new PMF(x*2);
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<x; j++){
        C.prob[i+j]=prob[i]*pmf.prob(j);
        return C;
        }
      }
   }
}
```

But then it shows me the error `This method must return a result of type of PMF.`

What am I doing wrong? The Method name(type) is given, so I cannot change it into void add(PMF pmf) or smth.

Comment: Before the method is returned before last bracket, add another return C; statement

Comment: Oh god, I can't believe I was that stupid. I honestly tried 20 different things without noticing it... Thank you!

Comment: Btw, how do I put a sign that you answered my question and stuff? I am new to this.

Comment: In the answer I have posted below, tick mark it underneath down vote button. T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PMF add(PMF pmf){
    PMF C= new PMF(x*2);
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<x; j++){
        C.prob[i+j]=prob[i]*pmf.prob(j);
        return C;
        }
    }
return C;
}
```